# Handling multiple exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally, multi-catch

My `abandon()` may throw `AbandonException`.

While handling the exception I have to recall the same method if there some element left in the `Vector`.

How should I proceed? And if I am not thinking straight, what would be the best solution?

```
   if (i + 1 < lc.size()) {
    try {
        lc.get(i + 1).abondon();
    }
    catch (AbandonException e1) {
lc.get(i+2).abandon();}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean recall the same method, but maybe you are looking for the `finally` block that will always execute even if there is no error?

Comment: Well my code calls abondon() inside a catch block of another abandon().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `finally` here.

```
try {
      lc.get(i + 1).abondon();
}
catch (AbandonException e1) {

} finally {
   your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

following is some pseudo-code:

```
List errorIndexList = new ArrayList();

for(...) {
    if (i + 1 < lc.size()) {
        try {
            lc.get(i + 1).abondon();
        } catch (AbandonException e1) {
            errorIndexList.add(i+1);
            // do some error handle work ..
            // print error log/info if need,
            continue; // this is optional, in case it's the last statement,
        }
    }
}

// use errorIndexList to handle your errors, if need,
```